# On scroll chart max value of data is not coming properly using highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock for scroll bar, for first time max value is coming properly but on scroll its not coming fine.

I set max value to 10 and when I am scrolling only 9 is showing.

Here is code, I am using:

```
this.xAxis = {
                    title: {
                        text: (this.Entities[0] && this.Entities[0].EntityType && this.Entities[0].EntityType in window.dashboardconfig.constants.statusOrder) ? window.dashboardconfig.constants.statusOrderText[this.Entities[0].EntityType] : ''
                    },
                    categories: _.map(this.Entities, function (sn) {
                        return sn.EntityName;
                    }),
                    min: 0,
                    max: (this.Entities.length >= 10) ? 9 : null,
                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: true,
                    }, 
var series = [{
                    name: (slotName in window.dashboardconfig.constants.statusOrder) ? window.dashboardconfig.constants.statusOrderText[slotName] : Resources.EventCode_5035,
                    data: _.map(this.Entities, function (entity) {
                        return entity.SlotValues.length >= index + 1 ? entity.SlotValues[index] : null;
                    }),
                    index: (slotName in window.dashboardconfig.constants.statusOrder) ? window.dashboardconfig.constants.statusOrder[slotName] : 0,
                    color: window.dashboardconfig.constants.statusColor[slotName]
                }];
                this.series = _.sortBy(series, function (item) {
                    return item.index;
                }).reverse();
```

Here 10 recoreds are coming in graph
[image]

But on scroll only 9 is coming
[image]

I don't know where I am doing wrong.Can please tell me what I is wrong.

Comment: The axis appears to be displaying properly - the 10th category is there. The data for the 10th category is not showing, so we'll need to see the rest of the code, or a fiddle example

Comment: I have updated the code where I taking the data.....

Comment: Can you recreate the problem on jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/dr2cuwp0/